# Get all segues connected to a view

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uistoryboardsegue

The identifiers I have for my segues contain data used to query a database. My problem is that after loading a view I need to cycle through all segues connected to a view to see if following that segue leads to meaningful results or not (if there will be any hits in the database). The segues are connected to tap recognizers.

How do I go around to found all segues connected with a view? Also will it from this view be easy to get the identifier for it?

Comment: That's really not what segues are for. It sounds like you need a method that performs your desired queries ahead of time, say early in the loading of this view controller, to determine if the view controllers it segues to will have results to show or not. The segue itself should have nothing to do with the query.